# Mapping accurate end time to start time for a video

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rdbms

I have 2 tables with start date and end date with video ids.
Table with Start time (Sample table with one user):

| Video ID | Start Time |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:20:00 |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:30:00 |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:42:00 |

Table with End time (Sample table with one user):

| Video ID | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:26:00 |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:45:00 |

1. A user can have multiple start times for a video if they started watching it multiple times.
2. The record will be in end time table only if the user had finished watching the video.
3. A user can start the same video again without ending it and the start time will be captured in the next row.

I want to map the start time and end time based on the recent video start time.

Desired Output:

| Video ID | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:20:00 | 22-01-2022 02:26:00 |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:30:00 | null |
| abc | 22-01-2022 02:42:00 | 22-01-2022 02:45:00 |

I tried joining the table with condition

`from start_time a left join end_time b on a.start_time<b.end_time`

But this will fill the 2nd start_time with 3rd end_time value which infact should be null.

Comment: Ideally you should have a column such as watch_ID in this model. Otherwise you will have to cook up some pseudo-column value and match against that.

Comment: Yeah, watch_ID would help but I don't have it. There is no unique identifier that would explain the sequence apart from time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date formats are appropriate, you can use below -

```
select s.vid,st,et from
(select vid_1.v_id as vid,start_time::timestamp as st,
min(timediff(second,start_time::timestamp,end_time::timestamp)) as tdiff 
from vid_1,vid_2 where st<end_time::timestamp group by vid,st) s left jo
IN
(select vid_2.v_id as vid,end_time::timestamp as et,
min(timediff(second,start_time::timestamp,end_time::timestamp)) as tdiff 
from vid_1,vid_2 where start_time::timestamp<et group by vid,et) e
on s.vid=e.vid and s.tdiff=e.tdiff order by st;

+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| VID | ST                      | ET                      |
|-----+-------------------------+-------------------------|
| abc | 2022-01-22 02:20:00.000 | 2022-01-22 02:26:00.000 |
| abc | 2022-01-22 02:30:00.000 | NULL                    |
| abc | 2022-01-22 02:42:00.000 | 2022-01-22 02:45:00.000 |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
3 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.426s
```